# Setup for SSL from AWS inside Docker

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, ssl

Beginner on setting this up so forgive me. So everything is okay if it's only http, but can't enable ssl for the site... not savvy enough on docker and ssl setup.

using laravel framework for backend and using reactjs for frontend.

so on AWS server, using apache. and docker.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:

### Redis session handler ########################
  redis:
    hostname: redis
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    image: redis
    expose:
      - "6379"

### Phalcon + Apache App container ###############
  app:
    hostname: neer_app
    container_name: neer_app
    build: ./docker
    working_dir: /application
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./application:/application:delegated
    depends_on:
      - redis

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: local

### nginx
```

**domain.com.conf** inside docker

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /application/public
    <Directory /application/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried the instructions from https://medium.com/@jevgenijdmitrijev/howto-configuring-server-for-hosting-single-laravel-web-ssl-with-lets-encrypt-f670710ef827 but it's not working.

Comment: What’s not working?

Comment: @mokugo-devops unable to use make the site run on https.